# Scipt: Input data in new cell based on value from specific cell and form submit auto fill a google doc

Tags: function, google-apps-script

I have a google form that inputs collected answers to a google sheet, with a script that auto fills a doc with the relevant information and emails to the selected recipient.  That all works.  Here is my problem.

I have one specific question on the Google Form with 5 options.  When an option is chosen, I have a specific research/quote that is associated with it.  I created a formula in the spreadsheet to pull that into the last column of the spreadsheet - which worked.
But...now when I submit the form with with this new info, the script does not work. I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
at onFormSubmit(Code:8:21)
I assume that the script is trying to get a value from the column I directed it to, but the formula did not operate fast enough for there to be a value there?

I am guessing I need to make this all happen in the script, so the info is put into the column I need first, then it pulls data from the spreadsheet to create the document and send the email.  I just don't know how to start...
I cannot even be considered a novice - a friend shared this code with me and I edit it when needed.

Ex: If answer choice in column F = Read, then column K should show "read quote"; If answer choice in column F = Write, then column K should show "write quote"; and so on.

My current script:

```
// Global variables 
var docTemplate = "1EoBcz0BK4R5hm-q5pR68xnQnR8DlR56XzjxRrgsu4uE";  // *** replace with your template ID ***
var docName     = "You got a High 5";

function onFormSubmit(e) { // add an onsubmit trigger
  
// Values come from the spreadsheet form  
   var observer = e.values[1]
   var teacher = e.values[2]
   var email = e.values[2]    
   var period = e.values[4] 
   var time = e.values[3]      
   var cif = e.values[5]    
   var image = e.values[6]
   var comments = e.values[7]
   var message = e.values[10]
 
       
// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
   var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
                .makeCopy(docName+' for '+teacher)
                .getId();
  
// Open the temporary document
   var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
  
// Get the document’s body section
   var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();
  
// Replace place holder keys,  
  copyBody.replaceText('keyobserver', observer);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyteacher', teacher);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyemail', email);  
  copyBody.replaceText('keyperiod', period);
  copyBody.replaceText('keytime', time);
  copyBody.replaceText('keycif', cif);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyimage',image);
  copyBody.replaceText('keycomments', comments);
  copyBody.replaceText('keymessage', message);

    
   var todaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy"); 
   copyBody.replaceText('keyTodaysDate', todaysDate);
  
// Save and close the temporary document
   copyDoc.saveAndClose();
  
// Convert temporary document to PDF by using the getAs blob conversion
   var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf"); 
  
// Attach PDF and send the email
   var subject = "High 5 - it matters.";
   var body    = "You got a High 5! See attached PDF. " +
                 "Please do not reply to this email.  You will be asked to supply a response thorugh a link within the attached PDF.  " +
                 "'Do all the good you can. By all the means you can. In all the ways you can. In all the places you can. At all the times you can. To all the people you can. As long as you ever can. -John Wesley'";
 
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
  // Delete temp file
   DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form submit trigger's event object will only capture the responses from the form written to the Google Sheet, not formulas done only in the sheet. That is why you are getting undefined error.

So you need to do your logic in the script itself:

```
var message;

if (cif == 'Read') {
  message = 'read quote'
}
else if (cif == 'Write') {
  message = 'write quote'
}
```

This is extremely simplistic, if you have a lot of choices for column F you might need to use `switch` instead of `if` statement.

Comment: Ok, I tried this but not working - I'm getting same error.  I currently don't have anything in column F.  My quote/message is in another sheet and the formula was pulling it into column F.  But the form collection does no input any data to that column currently.  I need to remove the formula completely from the spreadsheet - correct?  Where would I add your code?  I currently have it after getting values from the spreadsheet (around line 18).  And now that the message is no where in the sheet to pull from, does the code need to be altered?

Comment: Ok, got it to work!  Thank you so much!!  I really appreciate the help.